# C# Adding data to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

My code below reads a file offset and writes the hexadecimal values to the "MyGlobals.Hexbytes" variable .... How could I get it to write into an array instead?

Many Thanks

```
MyGlobals.Mapsettings_filepath = "C:\\123.cfg";

///////////////////////////// Read in the selected //////////////

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(MyGlobals.Mapsettings_filepath),
System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode);

for (int a = 32; a <= 36; a++)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = a;
    MyGlobals.Hexbytes += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2") + ",";
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what you want.  Do you want to change `MyGlobals.Hexbytes`?  And what type of array do you want?  A byte array, a string array, etc?  Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `MyGlobals.Hexbytes` to be `List<string>` instead then:

```
br.BaseStream.Position = a;
MyGlobals.Hexbytes.Add(br.ReadByte().ToString("X2"));
```

Later to display it, use `String.Join` like this:

```
string myBytes = string.Join(",", MyGlobals.Hexbytes.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Array is a fixed size structure, so you cannot add elements to it.

If you know the size in advance (as it seems in your example) you can instanciate it and then add elements to the pre-allocated slots:

e.g.

```
string[] byteStrings = new string[5]; // 36 - 32 + 1 = 5 

for (int a = 32; a <= 36; a++)
{
   br.BaseStream.Position = a;
   byteStrings[a - 32] = br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
}
```

But it's much easier to use a dynamically-resizable collection, like [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
var byteStrings = new List<string>();
for (int a = 32; a <= 36; a++)
{
   br.BaseStream.Position = a;
   byteStrings.Add(br.ReadByte().ToString("X2"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies...Is there anyway I can read 4bytes in instead of just one byte each time?

Comment: @user, what difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

You should first define the size of the array and thus you should first set its size and then populate it:

```
string[] array = new string[5];

for (int a = 32; a <= 36; a++)
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = a;
    array[a - 32] += br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
}
```

Here is how to read 4 bytes at once:

```
            BinaryReader reader = ....;
...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            reader.Read(buffer, 0, 4);

...
```

Comment: @user826436, I updated my answer with the code to read 4 bytes using binaryreader

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MyGlobals.Hexbytes`, which is likely, you could leave your code the way it is and add this in the end:

```
var myarray = MyGlobals.Hexbytes.Split(',');
```

`myarray` is an array of string.